# Passing multiple actions to onClick event in a react-bootstrap Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

Consider a react/redux application with react-bootstrap components.

This may be a very rookie question, but I am trying to pass multiple actions to a single onClick event on a Button from a react-bootstrap library.

```
<Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small" onClick={someCallback; someOtherCallback;}>
  Something
</Button>
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap them in another function:

```
<Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small" onClick={onButtonClick}>
  Something
</Button>
...
onButtonClick = function(event){
  someCallback()
  someOtherCallback()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do more than one thing when the button is fired

```js
function doMagic {
  //do something
  //do another thing
}
```

```html
<Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small" onClick="doMagic()">
  Something
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my application (using React JS + Bootstrap 5).
I wanted to use onClick to call an API (searchDataRange) and also to render a section of my page (const [renderItems, setRenderItems] = useState(false);)

.

I first tried this (**DID NOT WORK!**):

```
 <Button type="button" 
             className="btn btn-light mx-2"
             onClick={() => setRenderItems(!renderItems); searchDataRange} </Button>
```

I tried a few different combos with (), {}, etc.. but this solved the issue(**SOLUTION**):

```
  const trigger = () => {
    setRenderItems(!renderItems);
    searchDateRange();
 }

return(
```

```
 <Button type="button" 
             className="btn btn-light mx-2"
             onClick={trigger}>Search</Button>
             
            </div> ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there's OnClickCapture as well that works for a secondary Click Event.
Probably not the most efficient way,
but I think it works in the meantime if you use
**Onclick** for the first function and **OnclickCapture** for the second function.